# Is it possible to observe Rss feed change in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I want to create a service that would listen to few Rss feeds and parse new feeds to jSon for further use. Is it possible to observe to feed changes and if yes then how?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) namespace in the framework - it has pretty much everything you need to download feeds. Scott Guthrie has a couple of good example blog posts about reading feeds [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/22/Awesome-ASP.NET-2.0-RSS-Tool_2D00_Kit-Released.aspx) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to observe RSS feed changes is to poll the feed by requesting it over a set interval of time. This is because a feed is typically delivered over HTTP, which is a stateless request-response protocol and not a publish-subscribe protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out [RSS.NET](http://www.rssdotnet.com/), per it's website it can listen for changes.