# trying to read RSS Feed from BBC

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse RSS feed from BBC, but it return nothing !
RSS Feed

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/arabic/middleeast/index.xml
```

My code

```
var item = (from descendant in document.Descendants("entry")
                           select new NewsItem()
                           {
                               link = descendant.Element("link").Attribute("href").Value,
                               description = descendant.Element("summary").Value,
                               title = descendant.Element("title").Value,
                               image = " " // entry > link > img media:content > second media:thumbnail > url attribute
                               entry_date = DateTime.Now,
                               category = " " // second descendant.Elements("category") > label
                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why don't you use an RSS library? https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=rss

Comment: @Aron A library is not needed - it is already built into the .Net framework. [Previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7010922/109702). Let the inbuilt classes do the heavy work.

Comment: I was using SyndicationFeed, but it display error when it try to trunc publish date in RSS feed..

Comment: @dotfreelancer: It's not clear what you mean by "when it try to trunc publish date" but perhaps you should have asked a question about that instead of creating your own code for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for elements in no namespace. From the root element of the RSS feed:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
      xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
      xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
```

The `xmlns="..."` attribute specifies the *default* namespace for descendant elements (and that one).

So you want:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var item = document.Descendants(ns + "entry")
                   .Select(entry => new NewsItem
                           {
                               link = entry.Element(ns + "link")
                                           .Attribute("href").Value,
                               description = entry.Element(ns + "summary").Value,
                               title = entry.Element(ns + "title").Value,
                               image = " "
                               entry_date = DateTime.Now,
                               category = " "
                           })
                   .ToList();
```

Note how I've removed the query expression here, just using method calls instead - if a query is just "from x select y" then the query expression just adds cruft.

Additionally, I'd strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions (e.g. `EntryDate` instead of `entry_date` - although the value for that example is incorrect too...).

EDIT: As noted in comments, you could also use [`SyndicationFeed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed) or a third-party library to parse the feed. You're not the first person to want to parse RSS in .NET :)

Comment: oh, thanks about the namespace.. but i was asking about values problem.. i couldn't take the correct value from the RSS feed.

Comment: Not to detract from your excellent answer, but the OP could also use the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the entries.

Comment: @dotfreelancer: Well no, you wouldn't be able to - because you weren't finding the elements, because you weren't looking in the right namespace. You were looking for elements which weren't there, so it's no wonder that you couldn't find anything...

Comment: @slugster: True - have added a note on the answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet please see my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730537/syndicationfeed-error-when-i-try-to-access-publish-date